What don't I understand in topological sort using DFS?
Wikipedia says:

The algorithm loops through each node of the graph, in an arbitrary order, initiating a depth-first search that terminates when it hits any node that has already been visited since the beginning of the topological sort or the node has no outgoing edges (i.e., a leaf node)

Consider this graph:

If I start from the node A, then my DFS goes to C, then the order A, C, ... is created. But next I go to the node B and it gets wrong order A, C, B.
What do I misunderstand?

Is it an error in Wikipedia?

Main misunderstanding is when nodes are added to the answer - you add them when you leave them, right before/at backtracking
So you check A, check C, find that C is terminal - so you add C at the end of the answer
_ , _ , C
Then you roll back to A, check next child - B. Realise B only goes to an already visited node C, so it's "terminal" - add B to the latest available slot in the answer
_ , B , C
